# What are the semantic tableaux tree rules for exclusive disjunction?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

These are the rules for the traditional PL connectives:

[image]

How do I resolve the tree when there is in a exclusive disjunction (⊻) in an argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figuring that this is probably a homework question, I'll just give you a hint:

Just investigate the cases where an exclusive disjunction is true/false:

- $\alpha ⊻ \beta$ is true iff exactly one of them is true, that is

  - either $\alpha$ is true and $\beta$ is false
  - or $\alpha$ is false and $\beta$ is true.
- $\alpha ⊻ \beta$ is false iff they are both true or both false, that is

  - either $\alpha$ is true and $\beta$ is true
  - or $\alpha$ is false and $\beta$ is false.

Knowing that in a tableau tree, branching represents an "or" between conditions, vertical stacking corresponds to "and", and falsity is expressed by negating the formula, you can translate these truth conditions directly into a taleau rule.

As a further hint, note that exclusive disjunction is the negation of the biconditional: $\alpha ⊻ \beta$ is logically equivalent to $\neg(\alpha \leftrightarrow \beta)$, and $\neg(\alpha ⊻ \beta) \equiv \alpha \leftrightarrow \beta$, so the rule pairs will be the exact "opposite" of each other. That should make it pretty easy for you to figure it out now.

Comment: I'm a compsci grad learning logic in spare time. But I figured the trick was to resolve it using other connectives. Thanks :)